# Increasing The Amount Of Neurons In Hidden Layer

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network

I am working to understand how to build my own ANN from scratch.

I have looked around and found a simple two layer architecture and the `init_parameters` function is like this.

```
def init_parameters():
    W1 = np.random.normal(size=(10, 784)) * np.sqrt(1./(784))
    b1 = np.random.normal(size=(10, 1)) * np.sqrt(1./10)
    W2 = np.random.normal(size=(10, 10)) * np.sqrt(1./20)
    b2 = np.random.normal(size=(10, 1)) * np.sqrt(1./(784))
    return W1, b1, W2, b2
```

This is following the MINST data set. I understand that the input layer is `784` for each
`28x28` input image. For the hidden layer it is `10` if I am understanding the provided code. Lastly the output layer is `10` for each number from `0` to `9`.

My goal is to increase the number of neurons in the hidden layer.

This is what I have tried:

```
 def init_parameters():
    W1 = np.random.normal(size=(20, 784)) * np.sqrt(1./(784))
    b1 = np.random.normal(size=(10, 1)) * np.sqrt(1./10)
    W2 = np.random.normal(size=(10, 20)) * np.sqrt(1./20)
    b2 = np.random.normal(size=(10, 1)) * np.sqrt(1./(784))
    return W1, b1, W2, b2
```

This gives me an error when using my `forward_prop´ function

```
def forward_prop(W1, b1, W2, b2, X):
    Z1 = W1.dot(X) + b1
    A1 = ReLU(Z1)
    Z2 = W2.dot(A1) + b2
    A2 = softmax(Z2)
    return Z1, A1, Z2, A2
```

Error:

```
-> Z1 = W1.dot(X) + b1
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (20,29400) (10,1)
```

From the error it seems that the `b1` is not matched so I thought changing `b1` to `b1 = np.random.normal(size=(20, 1)) * np.sqrt(1./10)` will work and it did.

The new `init_parameters` is this:

```
def init_parameters():
    W1 = np.random.normal(size=(20, 784)) * np.sqrt(1./(784))
    b1 = np.random.normal(size=(20, 1)) * np.sqrt(1./10)
    W2 = np.random.normal(size=(10, 20)) * np.sqrt(1./20)
    b2 = np.random.normal(size=(10, 1)) * np.sqrt(1./(784))
    return W1, b1, W2, b2
```

Did I actually increase the neuron in the hidden layer and is this the right approach to what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: This looks right to me. If you're unsure, you could print out `Z1.shape`, which is the output of the first layer, and see whether it has 10 or 20 outputs per training example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you added 10 more hidden units (neurons) and there is nothing wrong with your approach. `W1` and `b1` contain the weights and biases of your first layer, and each row of those matrices represent a hidden unit.

From Andrew Ng's [Deep Learning course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks-deep-learning) (which uses notation similar to yours):
[image: Andrew Ng's neural network representation]

Notice the correspondence in number of hidden units and rows in the matrices.